# weak convergence and composition

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

Assume $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables defined on a common probability space and $X_n$ converges weakly (in distribution) to $X$ as $n \to \infty$. Assume $u_n$ is a sequence of integer valued random variables defined on the same probability space as the $X_n$, and satisfy $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n =\infty$ almost everywhere. Is it true that $X_{u_n}$ converges weakly to $X$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: The questions was extensively studied in the 70s and in the 80s. See for instance the linked papers: (http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2104808) and (http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2078756)

Comment: thanks very much for the 2nd paper, I didn't know it, although I searched on the topic. I knew the 1st one, but the second is much more useful in this case.